# OpenGL glAttachShader 1281 Error

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I am trying to create a OpenGL framework for a game that includes a shader function that parses a vertex Shader and a vertex fragment.

using the OpenGL Call to isolate the error and report a bug break at the line.

```
#define ASSERT(x)  if (!(x)) __debugbreak();
#define GLCall(x) GLClearError();\
x;\
ASSERT(GLLogCall(#x, __FILE__, __LINE__))
```

when the debug is reported, "[OPENGL Error]: <1281>", I get an error at this code:

```
GLCall(glAttachShader(program, vs));
```

which is used in this function:

```
static unsigned int CreateShader(const std::string& vertexShader, const 
std::string& fragmentShader)
{

GLCall(unsigned int program = glCreateProgram());
GLCall(unsigned int vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader));
GLCall(unsigned int fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader));

GLCall(glAttachShader(program, vs));
GLCall(glAttachShader(program, fs));
GLCall(glLinkProgram(program));
GLCall(glValidateProgram(program));
GLCall(glDeleteShader(vs));
GLCall(glDeleteShader(fs));

return program;

}
```

On the console window, it displays:

```
"Failed to compile shader! vertex"
ERROR: 0:7 'position' : undeclared indentified
ERROR: 0:7 'assign' : cannot convert from 'float' to 'Position 4-component vector of float'"
```

However, it still produces a blue quad on my screen.

Comment: Sounds like a bad shader.  Edit in a [mcve].  Feel free to use [this](https://pastebin.com/hqKPHd8C) as a base.

Comment: Is your question, why do I get output when the shader does not compile? Or why does my shader not compile?

Comment: "*using the OpenGL Call to isolate the error and report a bug break at the line.*" Your macro has that backwards. Your macro (don't use macros for this sort of thing) checks for errors *before* the function, not after. That's why you're getting the error on the wrong line. You should be using [Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output) anyway, rather than this macro solution.

Comment: @NicolBolas _checks for errors before the function_ Are you sure? `x; ASSERT(GLLogCall(#x, __FILE__, __LINE__))` looks for me like the right order (assuming `GLLogCall()` calls `glGetError()` which is unfortunately not exposed).

Comment: _`undeclared indentified`_ :-) You should've copy/pasted. It looks a bit ... non-authentic.

Comment: What does `CompileShader` do? The vertex shader does not compile. Do you delete it because of that? `glAttachShader` causes a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` (1281) error, if either the program object or the shader object is not valid.

Comment: You're still seing a blue quad, because either a different shader is loaded, or (*more likely*) you're running a *compatibility profile* OpenGL context and are falling back to the fixed function pipeline (essentially with modern GPUs kind of a default shader, that's controlled through a truckload of legacy OpenGL parameters set through state setting functions).

Comment: wild guess: `CompileShader` detects compilation failure and destroys the shader object again in that case (and either returns 0 or the name of a now invalid object)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your shader is being properly updated whenever you're building your code. Open the build directory and look for the shader file that you're using, and ensure that changes you're making to the source shader are reflected in the build version. A common error with shaders is that they are copied when the files are first created and then not updated.

I am following the same series by [TheCherno on YouTube](https://youtu.be/n4k7ANAFsIQ?list=PLlrATfBNZ98foTJPJ_Ev03o2oq3-GGOS2) as you, and I've been using CMake as my build system. It copied over the shader file when I first created it, but hasn't since. By adding the below line to my CMakeLists.txt I ensure that if there are any changes to the shader file that CMake will update the file.

```
configure_file(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/res/shaders/shader.shader ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/res/shaders/shader.shader COPYONLY)
```